# Restore numbering in Javascript table using for-loop

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, html-table

When I put data in my html table using javascript, every new row gets a number. When I put in the row number I then want to delete using my second inputfield, the row gets deleted but the numbers don't change. So when I have 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and I'm deleting 3, the numbers should go to 1, 2, 3, 4.

I am trying to this with a loop. Can somebody help me with this? This is the code I use:

```js
var addBtn = document.getElementById('addBtn');
var deleteBtn = document.getElementById('deleteBtn');
addBtn.onclick = addRow;
deleteBtn.onclick = deleteRow;
var rowNumber = 0;

function addRow() {
  rowNumber++;
  //Getting data from form
  var form = document.getElementById('form');
  var newData = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < form.length; i++) {
    newData[i] = form.elements[i].value;
  }
  //Adding data to table
  var table = document.getElementById('table');
  var newRow = table.insertRow();
  console.log(newRow);
  //add number to each row
  newRow.innerHTML = `<tr><td><i>${rowNumber}</i></td><tr>`;
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var newCell = newRow.insertCell(i);
    newCell.innerHTML = newData[i];
  }
  form.reset();
}

function deleteRow() {
  var input = document.getElementById('deleteRowInput');
  var tabel = document.getElementById('table');
  console.log(tabel);
  if (input.value == 0) {
    alert('Can not be 0!');
    return false;
  } else if (input.value > tabel.rows.length) {
    alert('This row does not excist!');
    return false;
  } else {
    tabel.rows[input.value].remove();
    input.value = '';
    return true;
  }
  //console.log(tabel.rows[rijId])
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <th>First name</th>
    <th>Last name</th>
    <th>Points</th>
  </tr>
</table>
<form action="" id="form" name="form">
  First name: <input type="text" id="fname"><br> Last name: <input type="text" id="lname"><br> Points: <input type="text" id="points">
</form>
<br>
<button type="button" id="addBtn">Add</button>
<br> Row number:<input type="text" id="deleteRowInput">
<br>
<button type="button" id="deleteBtn">Delete row</button>
```

Comment: The only way to keep numbers "logically" set, is updating each row after the one you just deleted and do `number = current - 1`.

Comment: And the problem is? Grab the rows and change the text of the first cell. All you need for this is already in _your_ script.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you implement a mecanism that "draw" your table from a data structure. Then you just need to store/delete your data from this structure and to "redraw" the table.

```js
var obj = [];

var table = document.getElementById("my_table");

function drawTable() {
  table.innerHTML = "";
  
  obj.map((data, i) => {
    var row = table.insertRow();
    row.innerHTML = `<tr><td><i>${i+1}</i></td><tr>`;
    
    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      var cell = row.insertCell();

      /* get your data here */
      cell.innerHTML = data[Object.keys(data)[j]];
    }
  });  
}

function add() {
  /* retrieve your data from your form here */
  obj.push({ firstname: "bar", lastname: "foo", points: 4 });
  
  drawTable();
}

function remove(index) {
  obj.splice(index, 1);
  drawTable();
}

setTimeout(() => add(), 1000);
setTimeout(() => add(), 2000);
setTimeout(() => remove(1), 3000);
setTimeout(() => add(), 4000);
setTimeout(() => add(), 5000);
```

```html
<table id="my_table"></table>
```